# is it possible to launch a window that does not stop the mainloop in python

Tags: python, window

OS = windows 7

I have a python program (works) that is listening to activity on the usb bus. I want to perform a lot of tests that require a particular user input at a particular time. I would like to pop up a window that says, "press button xxx". The key point is that the mainloop needs to continue running because it's looking for events. I don't care about the window or if it remains or not and I don't need to capture any information from the window. I just want a message to the user to press the correct button at the correct time. Any type of signaling would work; it doesn't have to be a gui window. It doesn't have to look pretty. Appreciate any suggestions or links to something like this. thx

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the operation of the Python script you're running does not depend upon the user input you request. To run another process without interrupting the Python script execution you can use:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen([exe,arg1,arg2,arg3])
```

where

*exe* = executable/script to run from your OS command line

*arg1*= first argument to pass to exe

*arg2*= second argument to pass to exe

*etc...* (as many arguments as your OS supports in a list)

This separate exe process could request input from the user.